# Livewire wire:model on Select Option not working properly

Tags: laravel, dropdown, laravel-livewire

I have a dropdown using wire:model

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Menu</label>
    <select wire:model="chapter_id" class="form-control @error('chapter_id') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Menu">
        @foreach ($chapters as $chapter)
            <option value="{{ $chapter->id }}">{{ $chapter->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @error('chapter_id')
        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
</div>
```

It works if I do change the option (the $chapter_id assigned successfully). But, if I leave it default (not change the option), or it has only an option, the $chapter_id will not assigned
[$chapter_id not assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsxzQ.png)

Can you guys help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to set a default value to `chapter_id`. I don't think there's another work-around. At least I didn't find any and it make sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

I see 2 ways to work around this. As tell the other before, one have an option for advice the user to select an option

```
<option value="">Please select</option>
```

and the other have a defaul value for this property

```
public $chapter_id = '1';
```

if this value is required on submit you have to refer it in the rules

```
protected $rules = [
'chapter_id' => 'required'
];
```

Answer (score 3):

`wire:model` is only set or updated on change. Hence if you are already on the item (or there is only one), it will not be triggered. You could work around this using `wire:init`, but I don't see much benefit compared to setting it directly in your `mount`-method of the component.

My solution is to add an "Please select" entry as the first one. This enforces to trigger a change by selecting the item in question (even if only one option is available).